Coronet and Coronet II benchmarks?
I'm reading about the IBM ASC project, and I see repeated references to a benchmark known as Coronet and/or Coronet II.
Does anyone know what this did?

That's about an ARPANET optical network. Unrelated.

Several mentions, but no details, in https://people.computing.clemson.edu/~mark/acs_end.html

The Coronet program was used by Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory, one of the two American nuclear weapons design establishments. So it almost certainly simulates some aspect of nuclear weapon detonation, but they won't be forthcoming about exactly what.
It is mentioned in the sidebar at the end of the ACS performance web page. It became part of the later Livermore Loops benchmark, and a 1981 Fortran version is shown. That says it is hydrodynamics code, which probably means it models part of the implosion process used to start a nuclear detonation. Since advanced implosion modelling is necessary for designing small and light nuclear weapons, secrecy is going to bite hard here.

Ahhh, that explains it. Much of the ASC documentation refers to two codes, one that does neutron diffusion and another that is hydrodynamic, so I guess these are one and the same.
